# Disable badges on Samsung Galaxy devices

Tags: notifications, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.2 JellyBean.

When I get notifications in SMS or from Facebook, I see a red notification with number (notification badges) on the application icon on home screen.

Is there a way to stop that? I stopped all notifications from Facebook app but I still get notification badges on home screen.

Comment: I have yet to find a way to do this with Touchwiz based ROMs I'm afriad. You could use an alternative launcher, and disable it (it is disabled in Nova Launcher by default). Or if you have root you could look for an Xposed Module, again though I haven't fond any of those either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this article](http://www.h3xed.com/computer-hardware/how-to-remove-icon-badge-notifications-on-android-samsung-touchwiz) that explains how to disable it on the Galaxy Note i717. I don't have a SG phone but I imagine the solution would be similar for yours.

1. Go to Settings > Manage Applications > swipe laterally through the top tabs until you reach "All"
2. Scroll down to locate `BadgeProvider` and tap on it
3. Click on the <kbd>Disable</kbd> button and confirm that you would like it disabled.

This will disable **all badge notifications** as there is no per-app setting interface.

Comment: Yape. That does it :) Its doesn't remove badegs already there but it does prevent new badges notification to appear. Thanks

Comment: This sounds like disabling badges for _all_ apps (incl. e.g. Messaging/SMS). Too bad there is no disabling per app like there is for notifications.

Comment: @DanielSparing that was not what the OP requested, so I didn't think to make any special note that it was a global setting. But you're right, it disables _all badges_.

Comment: One additional point that I would like to make is that the users have to scroll right 4 times to reach the "ALL" tab where they can find the "BadgeProvider" service.
At first, it wasn't obvious to me so I thought I didn't have that option. Glad I found it, so happy!!

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this does not work on the Galaxy S6, at least with Marshmallow. The BadgeProvider service cannot be disabled.